# google-services-auth crashes with kommunicate

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, kommunicate

I am trying to add [Kommunicate](https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/android-installation) services to my Android app.

But when I add the `dependencies` of kommunicate, I get an error stating that it crashes with the `google-services-auth` implementation

The dependencies section is as follows:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-blogger:v3-rev61-1.25.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'io.kommunicate:kommunicate:1.6.3'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.rom4ek:arcnavigationview:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.Commit451:ModalBottomSheetDialogFragment:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

The full `log` is as follows:

```
In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[15.0.1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[15.0.1], but play-services-basement version was 16.0.1.

The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have 
transitive dependencies that lead to the art
ifact with the issue.
-- Project 'app' depends onto io.kommunicate:kommunicate@1.6.3
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@16.0.1

For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your build.gradle file.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So silly of me!

The `play-services-auth` is version `15.0.1`:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
```

But not `16.0.1`:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
```